# Is this a participial phrase "with Moscow supporting President Bashar al-Assad and Turkey backing some rebel groups"?

Tags: grammar

I'm still confused what type of word classes the word "supporting" and "backing" in this sentence below, I think they function as participial phrase in this sentence? Am I right?

> Russia and Turkey back opposing sides in Syria’s nine-year conflict,
> with Moscow supporting President Bashar al-Assad and Turkey backing
> some rebel groups

Thank you for your help

Comment: They belong to the word class (part of speech) **verb**.

Comment: "Moscow supporting President Bashar al-Assad and Turkey backing some rebel groups" is a coordination of gerund-participial clauses functioning as complement of "with".